# Unwanted CSS Site Padding in Tablet & Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I created this site off of a PSD, all relatively elementary CSS. I have unwanted outside padding on a mobile device AND a tablet. I want the left and right edges of the site to be flush with the edges of the browser. Its about 20px of unwanted padding.

Please see my dev site:
http://america.82ndmedia.com/

I have tested removing the "margin: 0 auto" of the container div and it fixes it... however I need that for it to function on a desktop.

```
.container {
width: $w_total;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by the rule:

```
@media (max-width: 450px) {
   .header, .columns > .sidebar, .post_box, .prev_next, .comments_intro,
   .comment, .comment_nav, #commentform, .comment_form_title, .footer {
       padding-right: 13px;
       padding-left: 13px;
}
```

Either remove or override this rule somehow.

Comment: That did the job! Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using percentages instead of pixels because your current setup won't work and is hard to maintain using hardcoded pixels for a *responsive* design.

For example, you have your main wrapper `div class="container"` set to a `max-width` of `717px` on smaller screens *(which seems random)*, but inside of it you have elements like `id="blog"` set to a `width` of `1020px`, which obviously won't fit.

If you set those inner elements to percentages of their outer container, it'll be a lot easier to make it work and it'll be truly *responsive* or *fluid*.